# Apache Storm: Get Blob download exception in Nimbus log

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I am facing an intermittent issue in one of my storm clusters during deployment of new topologies (deployment process also includes killing of old version of same topology. We first deploy the newer version and then kill the old one). The problem is during the deployment, Nimbus UI crashes,
On looking at the nimbus logs we see wrappedKeyNotFoundException.

Nimbus log snapshot
[image]

Zookeeper log snapshot during the same time

[image]

Can you guide what could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

I also got very confused over these errors as they capture the full logs.
You can find more information on this at this Link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2905
There is also a GitHub merge request and discussion under: https://github.com/apache/storm/pull/2618

However, it still seems to be unresolved at all.